Unable to add external libraries
I am using c-lion and i have some cpp/h files and some external .lib/.dll files which are 32libs (glew32,glut32) . I am failing to link the external libs.
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `gluBuild2DMipmaps'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `glTexEnvf'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `auxDIBImageLoadA'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ziad\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1ufq3n.o:OpenGLMeshLoader.cpp:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
...

thats using MinGW
/out:OpenGLMeshLoader.exe 
OpenGLMeshLoader.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32.lib'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30153 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

thats using Visual Studio
Here is the cmake.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Graphics)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m32)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)


file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "src/*.cpp" "include/*.h")
add_executable(Graphics ${SOURCES})


link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


target_link_libraries(Graphics
        glew32
        glut32
        glaux
)


MinGW uses the GNU GCC compiler, whose libraries are named like libname.a. The libraries named like name.lib are only for MSVC.

Also, you're not linking with the actual OpenGL library (typically named gl).

@Someprogrammerdude im linking glut32.lib,glaux.lib,glew32.lib

Yes, but not gl.lib (or libgl.a for MinGW).

@Someprogrammerdude alright but it is still not linking showing can not open file using the visual studio compiler

And the .lib files are all in the directory where you tell CMake they will be (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)? Do you know where that actually is, the full path to it? Have you tried to use the actual full path to the directory?

Can not open a .lib in msvc usually means one or more of the following: 1. The lib is not found because its named differently or its not located in the library paths you told your linker to look, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3. The .lib file is corrupt.

Also just to make it clear about the .lib and .a discussion from above. You can't rename the extension to fix this problem. If the library is incompatible the extension isn't the problem.

@Someprogrammerdude currently i put them in the same dir as the cmake it started showing another errors ,
LINK2019,LINK2001 unresolved external symbol
OpenGLMeshLoader.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 65 unresolved externals

@drescherjm probably i am mixing 32 and 64. I changed the compiler settings to use msvc x86 , but even this give me another errors mentioned above
OpenGLMeshLoader.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 65 unresolved externals Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33130 for x86

Are the 65 unresolved external errors the same or different?

@drescherjm   same

Do a verbose build, to see the commands that are executed with all their flags and options.

@Someprogrammerdude i tired to do so but i do not know how, my guess so far what is happening. I am using clion with vstudio compiler, the build tool is ninja(I think here lies the problem, its cmake detected build tool). and the errors im receiving all related to unable to link glaux.lib. so what build tool should i use i have the .lib,.cpp,.h, and .dll files all in the same project dir.
Also it works fine using visual studio but im trying to migrate to clion
